# Getting error in handlebar pdf generation

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, pdf-generation, nodes

```
Unhandled Error Error: Command failed:
/node/NodeJS/sales.packages/sales.dev6.1.0.10131405.4884/libs/../node_modules/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs
/node/NodeJS/sales.packages/sales.dev6.1.0.10131405.4884/node_modules/html5-to-pdf/lib-phantom/html5-to-pdf.js
/tmp/tmp-96609fwa8zxt.j8r27qfr.html
/tmp/tmp-966091h65wl2.d81714i.pdf
/node/NodeJS/sales.packages/sales.dev6.1.0.10131405.4884/node_modules/html5-to-pdf
/node/NodeJS/sales.packages/sales.dev6.1.0.10131405.4884/node_modules/html5-to-pdf/pdf.css
/node/NodeJS/sales.packages/sales.dev6.1.0.10131405.4884/node_modules/html5-to-pdf/highlight.css
A4 portrait 1.5cm 500 html5bp
    PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the crash reporting guide at https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Crash-Reporting and file a bug report at https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/new with the crash dump file attached: /tmp/434f7682-c431-9f73-6a83851c-550f411e.dmp
    
        at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:204:12)
        at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
        at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
```

Comment: Trying to generate pdf using html template i am getting this error in logs. Please help

Comment: This question is unlikely to get any help without more information like a code snippet to reproduce the error and other solutions that you have tried.